# How to deploy java tools.jar in a netbeans native package?

Tags: java, netbeans, native, packaging, tools.jar

My javafx application use the java compiler. I've used netbeans to package it (EXE installer) on a windows machine, then installed it by double-click on the bundle. Then I get window error message: Error invoking method. - Failed to launch JVM. If I manually copy/paste tools.jar in installed runtime/lib folder (C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\myApp\runtime\lib), everything works fine. How to make that (or other possible correct solution) automatically when the package is created? I've alreardy tested the tools.jar inclusion in every possible netbeans project properties field with no success! Please Help, Tx

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, for now, my solution is..

Copy tools.jar from:

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\lib

to:

- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre\lib

And then, in netbeans, when you right-click on project to package as EXE installer, the tools.jar lib will be deployed to runtime/lib of the installed application..

That's it!